# Spring Boot - .dll already loaded in another classloader with two projects

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

i created two Spring boot projects.
One was the `test` project and the other is my `working` project

**Test project:**

With System.load i loaded the .dll to dir
The .dll is in the folders test project

**Working Project:**

Now iam trying to load the same .dll
The .dll is placed in my working folder

So every project have it own .dll

I get always in Error:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError **dir** already loaded in another classloader

**Do i have to "unload" the first .dll from the test project?**

**Is there any location where the tomcat is loading the .dll for my test project session so that i cant load the .dll again for my working project?**

Or

**How can i load the "already loaded" library?**

```
Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library C:\Dev\workspace\lightserver\src\main\libs\huesdk.dll already loaded in another classloader
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1907)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824)
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
```

Comment: Solution: I fixed this issue by deleting all .dll files. Look up where your classpath is and paste the .dll there. You can load the .dll directly by passing it directly through with System.load. If you use a classpath use System.loadLibrary("name of the library without .dll")

Answer (score 1):

Appeared when integrating external dll into spring, it throws java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkErrorabnormal:

```
Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library *\opencv_java400.dll already loaded in another classloader
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1907)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at com.jinbill.ocr.OcrApplication.<clinit>(OcrApplication.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:15)
```

Using spring-boot-devtools, springboot will reload the context during the run (it will be reloaded once at startup), so the link library will be prompted to load, directly in the location of the loaded dynamic link library plus try catch on the line:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AppApplication {
    static {
        try {
            System.loadLibrary(NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError ignore) {
            / / After using spring-dev-tools, the context will be loaded multiple times, so here will throw the exception that the link library has been loaded.
            / / If there is this exception, the link library has been loaded, you can directly swallow the exception.
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AppApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```